# Retraction and Homotopy type

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I need to describe an example of a subspace $A \subset X$ such that there is a retraction $r: X\rightarrow A$ but such that $A$ and $X$ do not have the same homotopy type? any hints? I was thinking about the torus $T^{2}$ and its subspace $A = S^{1}\times \{1\}$

Comment: Yes, that works.

Comment: If you're talking about deformation retraction, then it is not possible; a deformation retraction is a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was not sure about it!

Comment: No problem; you two invented most of Math --some 250 years ago!

Comment: Hahaha, We have problems with math too

Comment: Remember it has to be continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example works. They have distinguished fundamental groups and it's clearly a retraction.

Probably the easiest example is any non-empty space which is not contractible. There is always a retraction of a non-empty space onto a single point which is contractible and so not homotopy equivalent to the full space.